# Writing to csv Pandas

Tags: pandas

I am writing data to csv in pandas, some of data contains commas so I would like to write using quotes (""). How can I do this as I see only one character option for delimiter?

Comment: I don't understand the question. to_csv by default puts quotes around strings with commas. `pd.DataFrame({'col': ['test, data with comma', 'no comma']}).to_csv('test.csv', index=False)` -> `col\n"test, data with comma"\nno comma` Are you looking for something beyond the default behaviour?

Comment: Just save yourself the headache and choose a safe character for the delimiter that isn't found anywhere. Usually `|` is a safe bet if commas, semi-colons, and colons are already in use.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the character used as separator by passing `sep` argument to `to_csv` method.

```sh
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Raphael, Henri', 'Donatello'],
...                    'mask': ['red', 'purple, darkish'],
...                    'weapon': ['sai, one', 'bo staff']})
>>> sep=';'
>>> df.to_csv(sep=sep, index=False)
```

[to_csv method docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this question is about how to _"write using quotes ("")"_ and not how to change the csv delimiter to `;`.

Comment: @HenryEcker Then, ask the author to better clarify his question. In my opinion, as he is talking about `delimiter` I have showed him an example that works.